# Computer Vision - detecting face angle based on extracted face keypoints

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

I have an application which extract the basic keypoints of the face. This includes the the corners of the eyes, the corners of the mouth, the nose, and the face border.

Is there any build application or algorithm which I can apply so that I can detect the face angle(how much is it oriented to the left or how much is it oriented to the right)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I am looking over the internet for solution to this problem so that I can implement it. I am looking for articles which are dealing with this approach, but I couldn't find anything relevant so far. I was wondering whether someone else have dealt with this specific approach and maybe he can give me some direct guidelines articles or SDK or something...

Comment: Actually 2 points of eyes is enough. Connect eyes with line and draw a normal from the center. This normal is corresponds for angle.

Comment: The points are in 2D, they are image coordinates. How should I know how to detect the normal determined by them?

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/a6n5yecjn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to detect the face plane in 3D system. This would involve finding extrinsic parameters (orientation and pose) of the face plane with respect to camera. Base on how the face plane is related to image sensor plane, you can determine its orientation towards right and left.

There are numerous posts about extrinsic parameters in stackoverflow. A quick search would help you in finding the extrinsic parameters.

P.S : You will have to calibrate your camera, before you find extrinsic parameters